# What are the main differences between thread dump and heap dump?

Tags: java, spring-boot, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, spring-boot-actuator

What are the main differences between thread dump and heap dump ?

In Spring boot application actuator threaddump API (`http://localhost:8080/actuator/threaddump`) is returning json response.

What are the tools we can use for analyzing thread dump json response?

Answer (score 1):

- **Thread Dump vs. Heap Dump:**

***Thread Dump:***

> A thread dump is a snapshot of the current state of all    threads
> running in a Java application at a specific point in time. It
> provides information about the threads' states, their stack traces,
> and any potential thread contention or deadlocks. Thread dumps can be
> taken using tools like "jstack" command-line utility or by triggering
> a signal (e.g., SIGQUIT) to the Java process. Thread dumps help in
> analyzing and diagnosing thread-related issues in an application.

***Heap Dump:***

> A heap dump is a snapshot of the Java Virtual Machine's    memory at a
> specific point in time. It captures the objects and their
> relationships present in the heap, allowing developers to analyze
> memory consumption, identify memory leaks, and optimize memory usage.
> Heap dumps can be obtained using tools like Java VisualVM, Eclipse
> MAT (Memory Analyzer Tool), or other profiling tools.

**My preferred tool for analyzing thread dump, IntelliJ IDEA's JSON Tools:**

While IntelliJ IDEA doesn't offer specific thread dump analysis
features, it does have built-in JSON-related tools. You can use these
tools to format, validate, and navigate through JSON data.

1. Open your JSON thread dump in IntelliJ IDEA.
2. IntelliJ IDEA will automatically recognize the JSON format and provide you with formatting and navigation options.
3. You can use keyboard shortcuts like Ctrl + Alt + L (on Windows) or Cmd + Option + L (on macOS) to format the JSON and make it more readable.
4. Use the built-in JSON viewer to navigate through the JSON structure.

When dealing with thread dumps, you might need to rely on external tools like FastThread or Thread Dump Analyzer (TDA) to perform in-depth analysis and identify thread-related issues. Additionally, for heap dump analysis, tools like Java VisualVM or Eclipse MAT can help you understand memory usage patterns and address memory-related problems in your application.